# Getting error "object should be a named list" when plotting heatmap in R

Tags: r

I have recreated the error in this small example:

```
my_matrix <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
a = c("cat","dog","mouse")
my_groups <- as.data.frame(a)

p <- ComplexHeatmap::Heatmap(
        matrix = my_matrix,
        col = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "RdBu"),
    )

col = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "RdBu")

 p <- p + ComplexHeatmap::rowAnnotation(
            df = my_groups,
            col = col,
            show_annotation_name = TRUE)
```

> ```
> Error: `col` should be a named list.
> ```

Why am I getting this error, and what can I change in my code to prevent it?

Comment: col = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "RdBu")

I have edited to include that earlier.  The error is still present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument `col` should be a named list and elements in `col` should be named vectors. e.g.

```
col1 <- list(a = c(cat = "red", dog = "blue", mouse = "green"))
col1

# $a
#     cat     dog   mouse 
#   "red"  "blue" "green"
```

You can design the colors to corresponding rows of `my_groups`.

```
p + ComplexHeatmap::rowAnnotation(
  df = my_groups,
  col = col1,
  show_annotation_name = TRUE)
```

[image]

Of course, although I manually set colors one by one in my example, you can create fancy color vectors by `RColorBrewer` or other packages. Remember to make the vector and list named.

---

To make the example more complex:

```
a <- c("cat","dog","mouse")
b <- c(rep("group1", 2), "group2")
my_groups <- data.frame(a, b)

col1 <- setNames(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, "Set1"), a)
col2 <- setNames(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, "Dark2"), b)
col.list <- list(a = col1, b = col2)

# $a
#       cat       dog     mouse 
# "#E41A1C" "#377EB8" "#4DAF4A" 
# 
# $b
#    group1    group1    group2 
# "#1B9E77" "#D95F02" "#7570B3" 

p + ComplexHeatmap::rowAnnotation(
  df = my_groups,
  col = col.list,
  show_annotation_name = TRUE)
```

[image]